# MongoDB changestream notifications to only one consumer

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How do we ensure that only one process will get certain Mongo collection change notifications?  We run few processes which keep on listening on changes in certain collections. But all of them will get all the change notifications. 
We can use some external locks to address this issue, i.e. whichever process gets the lock, that will only subscribe to the change notifications and if the lock owner process dies/releses the lock, then some other process may get the lock and start listening for change notifications.

But is there any way to achive that natively from Mongo driver itself. I am looking for something like Kafka consumer group where it is guranteed that in a consumer group, only one consumer gets events from a partition.